# How to optimize this SQL query which select from the same table twice

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'm using the employees test database, available here: https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db
[image: Schema]

I'm trying to get names of employees who have the same last name as their manager. I wish to make the query below faster.

```
SELECT concat(first_name,' ',last_name) 
FROM  
((employees JOIN dept_emp ON employees.emp_no=dept_emp.emp_no) 
JOIN dept_manager ON dept_emp.dept_no=dept_manager.dept_no) 
WHERE employees.last_name=
(SELECT last_name FROM employees WHERE employees.emp_no=dept_manager.emp_no);
```

As you can see, there's a `select` in the `where` clause that searches the entire table. I assume that means for each row of the joined table, it will the entire `employees` table.
I tried to solve it by creating a smaller table before joining, but it's even 4x slower.

```
SELECT concat(B.first_name,' ',B.last_name)
FROM 
(SELECT employees.emp_no, employees.last_name, dept_no 
FROM employees JOIN dept_manager ON employees.emp_no=dept_manager.emp_no) AS A
JOIN
(SELECT employees.first_name, employees.emp_no, last_name, dept_no 
FROM employees JOIN dept_emp ON  employees.emp_no=dept_emp.emp_no) AS B
ON (A.dept_no=B.dept_no AND A.last_name=B.last_name);
```

Comment: What version of MySQL?  8.0 has `WITH`.

Comment: Version 8.0, can you write up a query? Indexing obviously makes things faster, so I'm just looking for a query improvement

Comment: Can a department have more than one manager?  If not, get rid of table `dept_manager` and add `dept_emp_no` in table `departments`.  If you are trying to keep a history of who worked for a dept when and track their movements?

Comment: Eh the schema is given, so I can't change that. Each departments can have more than 1 manager, but at different times (basically history)

Comment: You want names of _current_ employees...?  Is the `to_date` some time in the future?  Or maybe `NULL` means "current"?  If not, it is hard to optimize the query without knowing.

Comment: to_date and from_date doesn't matter in this question. The 2 example queries + the one in the current accepted answer gives the intended output, I just wonder if there's a faster query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) AS fullName
FROM employees 
    JOIN dept_emp ON dept_emp.emp_no=employees.emp_no
    JOIN dept_manager ON dept_manager.dept_no=dept_emp.dept_no
    # added after comment from Rick James
        AND dept_manager.from_date <= emp.end_date 
            AND emp.from_date <= dept_manager.to_date
    JOIN employees managers ON managers.emp_no=dept_manager.emp_no 
        AND managers.last_name=employees.lastname
```

From the top of my head. didnt test btw.

And add an index:
last_name

```
ALTER TABLE `employees` 
ADD INDEX `idx_lastName`(`last_name`) USING BTREE;
```

Comment: in the last line, there's no table managers

Comment: @HuyLe i aliased the employees table as managers there. I just re-joined employees as managers

Comment: https://www.dofactory.com/sql/alias

Comment: On the 2nd to last line, the "AND dept_manager" is missing something. If I remove it, this query becomes just as slow as my slow version. If I add "dept_manager.emp_no=dept_emp.emp_no", then the result is incorrect (only show the managers)

Comment: Sorry, edited the answer. Also dont forget to add the index to last_name

Comment: But I bet it is the index that's going to fix the speed

Comment: Okay, so indexing greatly improved the speed as expected, but is there any other way (better query statement)? If not, then I guess indexing is the only solution

Comment: The query as I have written above is a solid query, no weird things and all inner joins. Indexing IS the way to go here but it is also very logical. If that column is not indexed it will result in a full table scan (what you do not want). Always correctly index what you are joining on and whats in the where statement

Comment: That SQL says that _some_ employee at _some time_ had a matching name with _some_ manager at possibly _some other_ time.

Comment: @RickJames well yea, wasn't that the question? Ok I've got to agree, a group by could help filter out possible double's

Comment: @Firewizz - I read "same last name as their manager" to mean "at the same time.  Your answer fails to test for overlap of `from_date` through `to_date` to overlap.;

Comment: @RickJames Especially for you, I added the date restraint.

Comment: @Firewizz - This is simpler and should be more efficient: `AND dept_manager.from_date <= emp.end_date
AND emp.from_date <= dept_manager.to_date`

Comment: @RickJames good one, ill change this in the answer.